# Progressbar for Timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I want to make a progressbar for the milliseconds for this timer, but it don't work
Can you help me? Maybe it's simple but my app crash if a click on start ( button1 )

1:

```
 package com.example.stopwatch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
int i=0;
private ProgressBar pb;
private TextView textTimer;
private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMillies = 0L;
long timeSwap = 0L;
long finalTime = 0L;
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
```

2:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);

}
});
```

3:

```
pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
timeSwap += timeInMillies;
myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);

}
});

}

private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

public void run() {
timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

seconds = seconds % 60;
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
pb.setProgress(milliseconds);
textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);

}



};

}
```

Maybe you can help me.
Thx Jonah

Comment: Where do you initialize your `pb`?

Comment: If it's crashing then post `logcat` output.

Comment: maybe this is a bad question but how can i initialize my pb?

Comment: Define the progress bar in the xml then find it in a similar way to that which you found the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing because of this line I think

```
pb.setProgress(milliseconds);
```

I looked at it and cleaned it up a little bit. Now this has a working stopwatch for the textView. There is a progress bar that runs for no reason in your app though. I did not clearly understand your question though. Hopefully this gets you a start on your project.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
int i=0;
private ProgressBar pb;
private TextView textTimer;
private Button startButton, pauseButton;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMillies = 0L;
long timeSwap = 0L;
long finalTime = 0L;
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar); // here is the key
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
                textTimer.setText("b1 here showing startTime" + startTime);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                timeSwap += timeInMillies;
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
                textTimer.setText("b2 showing timeSwap" + timeSwap);
                break;
    }


}

public Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        pb.setProgress(milliseconds);   // because you call this
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);

    }



};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Hallo thank you for your answer. My App works fine without the progressbar but i want,  that the progressbar fills with the milliseconds.

Comment: Below the TextView initialization is the progress bar being initialized. If you want to style the progress bar (location, color) you do that in XML generally. If you want to control the progress bar generally that is best done through code in my experience.